# Computing the cohomology ring of $\mathbb RP^2 \times \mathbb S^3$ with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients.

Tags: homology-cohomology

Computing the cohomology ring of $\mathbb RP^2 \times \mathbb S^3$ with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients.

Here are my thoughts:

To use kunneth theorem and then knowing that the cohomology ring of $\mathbb RP^2$ is $\mathbb Z_2[\alpha]/ (\alpha^3)$ where $|\alpha=1|$ but what is the cohomology **ring** of $\mathbb S^3$ with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients?

Any clarification will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Either use the Universal Coefficient Theorem or compute the homology (by your favorite method) of $S^3$ with $\Bbb Z_2$ chains. Also, please stop using the group-cohomology tag; that has a completely different meaning.

Comment: what do you mean? Is the cohomology ring of the sphere is just its homology? @TedShifrin I do not understand your point, could you clarify please?

Comment: @Brain Clarification in these subjects is not possible in my opinion. You should google it and agree many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a reference in the internet. For $n$-dimensional sphere, I think,
$$H^*(S^n,\Bbb Z_2)=\Bbb Z_2[x]/(x^2)$$
where $x\in H^n(S^n,\Bbb Z_2)$ is a generator.

Comment: should not it be $n + 1$ in the denominator? Is not the $RP^2$ defined as $S^n$ with antipodal points identified? Does this help us in anything?

Comment: @Brain $x^2\in H^{2n}(S^n,\Bbb Z_2)=0.$ For second question: If $n=2$

Comment: so you are saying that this is the cohomology ring for any n sphere right? But how do you know this?

Comment: @Brain This is a long story to read. See Hatcher's book for example, Algebraic Topology. It is a popular book. There are better books. I am not so good. Abstract things.

Comment: You can know that this is true for the following reason: On the group level, for any abelian group $A$, we have $H^j(S^n;A) = A$ if $j=0,n$ and $0$ otherwise (use your favorite method, e.g. excision + long exact sequence and induct on dimension). Now if $A$ is a ring ($A = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in this question), we have $H^n(S^n;A) = A$ generated by some class $x$. The only possible multiplication that requires determining in $H^*(S^n;A)$ is $x^2$. But $x^2$ lies in $H^{2n}(S^n;A)$ which is zero. The ring that expresses these two rules is $A[x]/(x^2)$. Now set $A = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Brain Will you notify us when you computed $H^*(\Bbb RP^3\times \Bbb S^3; \Bbb Z_2)$ in terms of generators and relations?

Comment: hahaha :) sure why not?